# Finite ring extension of local rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> Let $R$ and $S$ be local rings with the maximal ideals $M$ and $N$, respectively. Assume that $R\subset S$ and that $S$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. If there exists a proper ideal $I$ of $R$ such that $I=IS \cap R$ and the canonical image of $R/I$ in $S/IS$ equals $S/IS$, then prove that $R=S$.

I think that I need to do something with Nakayama's lemma but I couldn't get anything so far. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second  hypothesis says 
$$R+IS/IS=S/IS\iff S=R+IS$$
As $S$ is a finite $R$-module, *Nakayama's lemma* says there exists an element $a\in I$ such that $(1+a)S\subset R $. As $I$ is contained in the radical of $R$, $1+a$ is a unit in $R$, so really $S\subset R$. As the reverse inclusion is in the hypotheses, this proves $S=R$.

Comment: Could you explain how you get the third line by the second hypothesis?

Comment: Do you mean the reference to Nakayama's lemma?

Comment: No, how you get the line  beginning with $R+IS/IS=IS$ ? Thanks.

Comment: Well, the image of $R$ (hence of $R/I$) in $S/IS$ is precisely $(R+IS)/IS$. Isn't that clear? Furthermore, by the Second Isomorphism theorem, it is isomorphic to $R/(IS\cap R)ˆ=R/I$.

Comment: No, it is not clear for me, but thanks, I will try to understand that part, the rest is ok.

Comment: I suppose you agree at least that this image is *contained* in $(R+IS)/IS$?

Comment: I think I got it, thanks though.

Comment: Why need that detour instead of concluding that $R=S$ directly from $S=R+IS$?

Comment: @user26857: I wanted to recall the general version of Nakayama's lemma: all other versions are a consequence of this one. But you're right: it could be shortened.